# Lets say dad class have two child object class. How can call functions these childs from each others ? C++

Tags: c++

I want to say this at title:

game.h

```
#include "player.h"
#include "network.h"

class game
{
    public:


    player p1;
    network net;

}
```

network.h

```
class network
{
    public:


    void networkFunction1();

}
```

when i was in player.cpp i want to reach networkFunction1();

Comment: ***when i was in player.cpp i want to reach networkFunction1()*** You can't directly. `p1` has no connection to `net`

Comment: it's not clear what you want. Can you please elaborate? Give an example of an usage.

Comment: If you have pointer or reference to object of type `network` then you can call its member function `networkFunction1()`.

Comment: You need to arrange for `player.cpp` to have visibility of an instance of `net`.   That requires both including `network.h` and some code that has visibility of an instance of `net` (e.g. that creates one, that provides a reference or pointer to one provided elsewhere BEFORE you need it).  Then the solution is simply to call the member function using that instance.  e.g. `some_instance.networkFunction1()` or `some_pointer->networkFunction1()`

Comment: thanks for answers guys. i applied below Martin way and it worked good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways. One of them is to pass the `network`'s address to `player`, who can use it later:

```
class player {
    network *net;

public:
    void setNetwork(network *netPtr) {
        net = netPtr;
    }
}

class game {
public:
    player p1;
    network net;

    game() {
        p1.setNetwork(&net);
    }
}
```

Then, in methods of `player` class, you can use the `network` like this:

```
net->networkFunction1();
```